# Alpacajs forms: how to set the content-type to json?

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

It seems to be that there is no option to specify the content-type header, when submitting an alpacajs form.

All forms are submitted as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** which is a little strange to my taste, since Alpaca is all about json. It's also not listed in the documentation.

So my question: how do I submit my form as JSON content type?

Laravel states the following in it's documentation "**[When sending JSON requests to your application, you may access the JSON data via the input method as long as the Content-Type header of the request is properly set to application/json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
var data = $('#my-form').alpaca().getValue();

$.ajax('/endpoint', {
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

Or alternatively

```
$('#my-form').alpaca({
  schema: {..},
  options: {
    form: {
      buttons: {
        submit: {
          type: 'button',
          click: function(){
            var val = this.getValue();
            // Repeat ajax call from above.
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```